# Python Selenium WebDriver drag-and-drop

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I cannot get drag-and drop working with the Python WebDriver bindings. I am working with Google Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X. There is a thread [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1279) where someone had a similar problem.

I have tried using `ActionsChains`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

actionChains.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform()
```

Have you managed to get the Python WebDriver drag-and-drop working?

Comment: It might help if you mentioned a concrete problem you are having.

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks. I've updated the question. I'm trying to drag `source` to `target`. I've posted some code.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with `source` or `target`. Maybe show those too?

Comment: I've verified my `source` and `target`. They are what they should be. (`source = driver.find_by_id('#source')` etc.). Somehow I think there is a problem with `actionChains.move_to_element(source)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the sake of giving an updated answer, I have verified that this does in fact work on Mac now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your.site.with.dragndrop.functionality.com")
source_element = driver.find_element_by_name('your element to drag')
dest_element = driver.find_element_by_name('element to drag to')
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform()
```

[Reference](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 6):

Action Chains don't currently work on Mac. If you tried the code above on Linux or Windows it would work. ChromeDriver is close to getting this right but still needs work AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any idea of the time frame of this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a timeframe. A number of people have tried to see what to and get close but we need to have it on par with other platforms before we release

Comment: Is there any update on this? Do you have any links to related issue tickets?

Answer (score 3):

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(source).pause(4).move_to_element(target).release(target).perform()
```

This will also do drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly without some sample HTML for the source and the target.

You could try using `drag_and_drop_by_offset(self, source, xoffset, yoffset)` instead with a small value for the offset parameters. Sometimes that works.

You could also try to adapt [this C# example](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/selenium-rc/selenium-mousedownat-mousemoveat-and-mouseupat-example/) which uses `mouse_down_at`, `mouse_move_at` and `mouse_up_at` instead.