# Drag-and-drop with ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to do drag-and-drop with ChromeDriver. The only WebDriver way of doing drag-and-drop I found is using the "advanced user interactions API". Unfortunately, the [ChromeDriver documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) has the following "known issue":

> Advanced user interactions API not implemented

Is there a way to perform drag-and-drop *without* the advanced user interactions API?

<sub>[Details: I'm using the Python bindings of WebDriver (version 2.17), and Chrome 16 on Mac OS 10.7.]</sub>

Comment: Would appreciate a comment from the downvoter!

Comment: I imagine it got down voted becuase you answered your own question, drag-drop is not in the list of supported Actions so it is not supported.

Comment: @Stuart: My question is weither or not there is *another* way to implement drag-and-drop.

Comment: ahh, I didn't get that from your question, afraid I dont know in that case.  hopefully someone else can help you, good luck

Comment: related: [Python Selenium WebDriver drag-and-drop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8833835/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, drag-and-drop *did* end up working with WebDriver, just very inconsistently.

Comment: Can you confirm about this issue while using ruby and watir-webdriver? Still in today's, it is working in firefox, but not in chrome consistently! And can you inform that your "For some reason", what it was?