# How to change position of dragable child elements with in same parent using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Suppose I have this html.

```
<div name="parent">
    <div name="child one"> </div>
    <div name="child two"> </div>
    <div name="child three"> </div>
    <div name="child four"> </div>
</div>
```

All of these child elements are dragable but can't be placed outside of their parent element.

My question is how can i tell selenium-python that drag **child one** and drop it next to **child four** ??

So resulting html should be like this.

```
<div name="parent">
    <div name="child two"> </div>
    <div name="child three"> </div>
    <div name="child four"> </div>
    <div name="child one"> </div>
</div>
```

I have been searching around. 
like [Selenium-python-readthedocs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#drag-and-drop) 
and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833835/python-selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop)

But I found nothing related to my problem.

Comment: If you are voting negative. Please point out what is wrong with the question ? So I can improve it.

Comment: Generally people want to see that you have tried something on your own. You did good by doing some research and proved that you did some by posting some relevant links. You should post the code that you have tried and what the result was. It may help us better understand what you are trying to do and possibly how to correct your code or help you in some way. I didn't downvote so I'm only guessing...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)? It allows for drag and drop.

```
childOne = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.child.one")
childFour = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.child.four")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.drag_and_drop(childOne, childFour)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: it do the dragging but doesn't do dropping.

Comment: And also logically. this answer is not providing that either source element should be before target element or after target element ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. The order of the elements in the HTML doesn't matter. There are other methods in `ActionChains` that you can try and see if they work.

Comment: OK, let me elaborate to you. I am testing a invoice generation system. When creating invoice, there are sections and these sections are rearrangeable. I am making a test that when you drag one section and change its position then the order of my sorting section should be changed. These child divs are those sections.

Comment: Order of html is important, from that i will check that by dragging some elements change its order in the template

Comment: OK. That makes sense... but to my point, when you find an element by id, etc., it doesn't matter where in the HTML it is (with the exception of inside `IFRAME`s)... it's still found. You can still find `one` and drop it on `four` no matter the order. Now... you will probably want to verify that it moved so in that case you will make sure that the order of the `DIV`s has changed in the HTML.

Comment: I don't remember for sure but my guess is that `drag_and_drop()` probably drops the element in the center of the target element. That may not be what you want. That's why I was suggesting that you investigate the other methods in `ActionChains`, e.g. `drag_and_drop_by_offset()`. That may get you what you want if what you want is to drag element 1 to the right of element 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In case of JAVA, this is the solution, can you look up for the same in python ?

```
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from web element)  
             .moveToElement(toElement)     
            .release(To)     
           .build();     
dragAndDrop.perform();
```