# How to do mouse right click and drag with selenium webdriver in python or with only python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to do right click and drag on canvas element how can do it using selenium webdriver in python.

I want to perform this on canvas element
mouse right click down + drag + mouse right click up

I have tried below but doesnot work,

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(canvas).click_and_hold(canvas).release().perform()
```

Comment: see if this works ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform() and also possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833835/python-selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop

Comment: i have the source and dest element to be canvas element

Comment: drag_and_drop_by_offset(canvas, xoffset, yoffset) works but not sure if its doing mouse left click and drag or mouse right click and drag. any ideas? thanks