# unable to find correct XPATH for selenium drag and drop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm building a python script to help upload to beatstars quicker, however I'm having an issue locating the correct element to click on. As well as finding the XPATH. As of now I have no issue opening chrome, moving to beatstars, and pressing the upload button, however once doing so a modal pops up with a drag and drop section:
[image]

The issue I have is with locating the correct button to click to open browse or if there's a better way like just copying the file directly into the section. This is the html for this.

```
<mat-dialog-container
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-modal="true"
  class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c25-86 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted"
  id="mat-dialog-5"
  role="dialog"
  style="transform: none"
  ><ng-component _nghost-jyk-c105="" class="ng-star-inserted"
    ><mat-dialog-content
      _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
      class="mat-dialog-content upload-dialog-content"
      ><div _ngcontent-jyk-c105="" class="header">
        <h3 _ngcontent-jyk-c105="">Single file upload</h3>
        <button _ngcontent-jyk-c105="" class="ng-star-inserted" style="">
          <i
            _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
            class="vb-icon-close-m-regular-solid"
          ></i></button
        ><!---->
      </div>
      <mat-tab-group
        _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
        class="mat-tab-group mat-primary ng-star-inserted"
        style=""
        ><mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header"
          ><div
            aria-hidden="true"
            mat-ripple=""
            class="mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-before mat-elevation-z4 mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled"
          >
            <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination-chevron"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mat-tab-label-container">
            <div
              role="tablist"
              class="mat-tab-list"
              style="transform: translateX(0px)"
            >
              <div class="mat-tab-labels">
                <div
                  role="tab"
                  mattablabelwrapper=""
                  mat-ripple=""
                  cdkmonitorelementfocus=""
                  class="mat-ripple mat-tab-label mat-focus-indicator mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted"
                  id="mat-tab-label-4-0"
                  tabindex="0"
                  aria-posinset="1"
                  aria-setsize="4"
                  aria-controls="mat-tab-content-4-0"
                  aria-selected="true"
                  aria-disabled="false"
                >
                  <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                    <i
                      _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                      class="vb-icon-cloud-upload-file-m-regular ng-star-inserted"
                    ></i>
                    Upload
                    <!----><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  role="tab"
                  mattablabelwrapper=""
                  mat-ripple=""
                  cdkmonitorelementfocus=""
                  class="mat-ripple mat-tab-label mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted"
                  id="mat-tab-label-4-1"
                  tabindex="-1"
                  aria-posinset="2"
                  aria-setsize="4"
                  aria-controls="mat-tab-content-4-1"
                  aria-selected="false"
                  aria-disabled="false"
                >
                  <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                    <i
                      _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                      class="vb-icon-drive-m-regular-solid ng-star-inserted"
                    ></i>
                    Google Drive
                    <!----><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  role="tab"
                  mattablabelwrapper=""
                  mat-ripple=""
                  cdkmonitorelementfocus=""
                  class="mat-ripple mat-tab-label mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted"
                  id="mat-tab-label-4-2"
                  tabindex="-1"
                  aria-posinset="3"
                  aria-setsize="4"
                  aria-controls="mat-tab-content-4-2"
                  aria-selected="false"
                  aria-disabled="false"
                >
                  <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                    <i
                      _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                      class="vb-icon-dropbox-m-regular-solid ng-star-inserted"
                    ></i>
                    Dropbox
                    <!----><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  role="tab"
                  mattablabelwrapper=""
                  mat-ripple=""
                  cdkmonitorelementfocus=""
                  class="mat-ripple mat-tab-label mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted"
                  id="mat-tab-label-4-3"
                  tabindex="-1"
                  aria-posinset="4"
                  aria-setsize="4"
                  aria-controls="mat-tab-content-4-3"
                  aria-selected="false"
                  aria-disabled="false"
                >
                  <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                    <i
                      _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                      class="vb-icon-link-m-regular-solid ng-star-inserted"
                    ></i>
                    Import URL
                    <!----><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
              </div>
              <mat-ink-bar
                class="mat-ink-bar"
                style="visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 160px"
              ></mat-ink-bar>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            aria-hidden="true"
            mat-ripple=""
            class="mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-after mat-elevation-z4 mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled"
          >
            <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination-chevron"></div></div
        ></mat-tab-header>
        <div class="mat-tab-body-wrapper">
          <mat-tab-body
            role="tabpanel"
            class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c115-87 mat-tab-body-active ng-star-inserted"
            id="mat-tab-content-4-0"
            aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-4-0"
            ><div
              cdkscrollable=""
              class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c115-87 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab"
              style="transform: none"
            >
              <!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
              <div
                _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                class="step ng-star-inserted"
                style=""
              >
                <div _ngcontent-jyk-c105="" class="drag-drop-container">
                  <div _ngcontent-jyk-c105="" class="drag-drop-message">
                    <div _ngcontent-jyk-c105="" class="icons">
                      <i
                        _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                        class="vb-icon-cloud-upload-file-m-regular"
                      ></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4 _ngcontent-jyk-c105="">
                      Drag &amp; Drop, or <a _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""> Browse </a>
                    </h4>
                    <label
                      _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                      class="file-type ng-star-inserted"
                      ><!----><span
                        _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                        class="ng-star-inserted"
                      >
                        .mp3 or .wav </span
                      ><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></label
                    ><!---->
                  </div>
                  <div
                    _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                    id="uppy-drag-drop"
                    data-qa="uppy_drag_drop"
                    class="uppy-box"
                  >
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="uppy-Root uppy-u-reset uppy-DragDrop-container uppy-DragDrop--isDragDropSupported"
                      style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
                    >
                      <input
                        class="uppy-DragDrop-input"
                        type="file"
                        hidden=""
                        name="files[]"
                        multiple=""
                        accept="audio/mp3,audio/x-mp3,audio/mpeg,audio/mpeg3,audio/x-mpeg-3,audio/wav,audio/x-wav,audio/wave,audio/x-wave,audio/vnd.wave,application/octet-stream"
                      />
                      <div class="uppy-DragDrop-inner">
                        <svg
                          aria-hidden="true"
                          focusable="false"
                          class="uppy-c-icon uppy-DragDrop-arrow"
                          width="16"
                          height="16"
                          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                        >
                          <path
                            d="M11 10V0H5v10H2l6 6 6-6h-3zm0 0"
                            fillRule="evenodd"
                          ></path>
                        </svg>
                        <div class="uppy-DragDrop-label">
                          Drop files here or
                          <span class="uppy-DragDrop-browse">browse</span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="uppy-DragDrop-note"></span>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div _ngcontent-jyk-c105="" class="my-files ng-star-inserted">
                  <label _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""> My files </label
                  ><bs-secondary-uploaded-files
                    _ngcontent-jyk-c105=""
                    _nghost-jyk-c136=""
                    class="ng-star-inserted"
                    style=""
                    ><div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="uploaded-files">
                      <ul
                        _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                        class="files-uploaded ng-star-inserted"
                      >
                        <li
                          _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                          id="row-0"
                          class="ng-star-inserted"
                        >
                          <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="left">
                            <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-type-icon">
                              <i
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                class="icon-music-4"
                              ></i>
                            </div>
                            <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-info">
                              <span _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-name"
                                >j-cole-type-beat</span
                              >
                              <div
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                class="secondary-info ng-star-inserted"
                              >
                                <span _ngcontent-jyk-c136="">26.00 MB</span
                                ><span
                                  _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                  class="ng-star-inserted"
                                  >&nbsp;∙&nbsp;</span
                                ><!----><span _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                  >Sep 2, 2022, 6:05 PM</span
                                >
                              </div>
                              <!---->
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="right">
                            <bs-menu-more-options
                              _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                              class="menu-more-options"
                              _nghost-jyk-c93=""
                              ><div
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                class="mat-menu-trigger wrapper-button"
                                style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px"
                              >
                                <button
                                  _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                  mat-icon-button=""
                                  class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base ng-star-inserted"
                                  aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-9"
                                  cdk-describedby-host=""
                                >
                                  <span class="mat-button-wrapper"
                                    ><i
                                      _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                      class="icon-dots ng-star-inserted"
                                    ></i
                                    ><!----></span
                                  ><span
                                    matripple=""
                                    class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"
                                  ></span
                                  ><span
                                    class="mat-button-focus-overlay"
                                  ></span></button
                                ><!----><!---->
                              </div>
                              <!----><mat-menu
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                class="ng-star-inserted"
                                ><!----></mat-menu
                              ><!----><!----></bs-menu-more-options
                            ><bs-square-button
                              _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                              buttontype="button"
                              class="btn-select ng-star-inserted"
                              _nghost-jyk-c103=""
                              ><button
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c103=""
                                bssquarebuttonfocus=""
                                type="button"
                                class="action-element primary ng-star-inserted"
                              >
                                Select
                                <!----></button
                              ><!----><!----><!----></bs-square-button
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </div>
                          <div
                            _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                            class="border-bottom"
                          ></div>
                        </li>
                        <li
                          _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                          id="row-1"
                          class="ng-star-inserted"
                        >
                          <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="left">
                            <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-type-icon">
                              <i
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                class="icon-music-4"
                              ></i>
                            </div>
                            <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-info">
                              <span _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-name"
                                >island-girl</span
                              >
                              <div
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                class="secondary-info ng-star-inserted"
                              >
                                <span _ngcontent-jyk-c136="">27.10 MB</span
                                ><span
                                  _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                  class="ng-star-inserted"
                                  >&nbsp;∙&nbsp;</span
                                ><!----><span _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                  >Aug 31, 2022, 10:47 PM</span
                                >
                              </div>
                              <!---->
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="right">
                            <bs-menu-more-options
                              _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                              class="menu-more-options"
                              _nghost-jyk-c93=""
                              ><div
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                class="mat-menu-trigger wrapper-button"
                                style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px"
                              >
                                <button
                                  _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                  mat-icon-button=""
                                  class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base ng-star-inserted"
                                  aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-9"
                                  cdk-describedby-host=""
                                >
                                  <span class="mat-button-wrapper"
                                    ><i
                                      _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                      class="icon-dots ng-star-inserted"
                                    ></i
                                    ><!----></span
                                  ><span
                                    matripple=""
                                    class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"
                                  ></span
                                  ><span
                                    class="mat-button-focus-overlay"
                                  ></span></button
                                ><!----><!---->
                              </div>
                              <!----><mat-menu
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                class="ng-star-inserted"
                                ><!----></mat-menu
                              ><!----><!----></bs-menu-more-options
                            ><bs-square-button
                              _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                              buttontype="button"
                              class="btn-select ng-star-inserted"
                              _nghost-jyk-c103=""
                              ><button
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c103=""
                                bssquarebuttonfocus=""
                                type="button"
                                class="action-element primary ng-star-inserted"
                              >
                                Select
                                <!----></button
                              ><!----><!----><!----></bs-square-button
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </div>
                          <div
                            _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                            class="border-bottom"
                          ></div>
                        </li>
                        <li
                          _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                          id="row-2"
                          class="ng-star-inserted"
                        >
                          <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="left">
                            <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-type-icon">
                              <i
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                class="icon-music-4"
                              ></i>
                            </div>
                            <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-info">
                              <span _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="file-name"
                                >island-girl</span
                              >
                              <div
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                class="secondary-info ng-star-inserted"
                              >
                                <span _ngcontent-jyk-c136="">3.69 MB</span
                                ><span
                                  _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                  class="ng-star-inserted"
                                  >&nbsp;∙&nbsp;</span
                                ><!----><span _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                                  >Aug 31, 2022, 10:47 PM</span
                                >
                              </div>
                              <!---->
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div _ngcontent-jyk-c136="" class="right">
                            <bs-menu-more-options
                              _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                              class="menu-more-options"
                              _nghost-jyk-c93=""
                              ><div
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                class="mat-menu-trigger wrapper-button"
                                style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px"
                              >
                                <button
                                  _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                  mat-icon-button=""
                                  class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base ng-star-inserted"
                                  aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-9"
                                  cdk-describedby-host=""
                                >
                                  <span class="mat-button-wrapper"
                                    ><i
                                      _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                      class="icon-dots ng-star-inserted"
                                    ></i
                                    ><!----></span
                                  ><span
                                    matripple=""
                                    class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"
                                  ></span
                                  ><span
                                    class="mat-button-focus-overlay"
                                  ></span></button
                                ><!----><!---->
                              </div>
                              <!----><mat-menu
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c93=""
                                class="ng-star-inserted"
                                ><!----></mat-menu
                              ><!----><!----></bs-menu-more-options
                            ><bs-square-button
                              _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                              buttontype="button"
                              class="btn-select ng-star-inserted"
                              _nghost-jyk-c103=""
                              ><button
                                _ngcontent-jyk-c103=""
                                bssquarebuttonfocus=""
                                type="button"
                                class="action-element primary ng-star-inserted"
                              >
                                Select
                                <!----></button
                              ><!----><!----><!----></bs-square-button
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </div>
                          <div
                            _ngcontent-jyk-c136=""
                            class="border-bottom"
                          ></div>
                        </li>
                        <!---->
                      </ul>
                      <!----><!---->
                    </div></bs-secondary-uploaded-files
                  ><!----><!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
              </div>
              <!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
            </div></mat-tab-body
          ><mat-tab-body
            role="tabpanel"
            class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c115-88 ng-star-inserted"
            id="mat-tab-content-4-1"
            aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-4-1"
            ><div
              cdkscrollable=""
              class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c115-88 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab"
              style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px); min-height: 1px"
            >
              <!---->
            </div></mat-tab-body
          ><mat-tab-body
            role="tabpanel"
            class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c115-89 ng-star-inserted"
            id="mat-tab-content-4-2"
            aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-4-2"
            ><div
              cdkscrollable=""
              class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c115-89 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab"
              style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px); min-height: 1px"
            >
              <!---->
            </div></mat-tab-body
          ><mat-tab-body
            role="tabpanel"
            class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c115-90 ng-star-inserted"
            id="mat-tab-content-4-3"
            aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-4-3"
            ><div
              cdkscrollable=""
              class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c115-90 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab"
              style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px); min-height: 1px"
            >
              <!---->
            </div></mat-tab-body
          ><!---->
        </div></mat-tab-group
      ><!----><!----><!----><!----></mat-dialog-content
    ></ng-component
  ><!----></mat-dialog-container
>
```

I'm new to selenium and can't find the write thing to try and click on:

This is my code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

email = browser.find_element(By.ID, "oath-email").send_keys(username, Keys.ENTER)

password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "userPassword"))).send_keys(password, Keys.ENTER)

new_track = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/studio-root/div/ng-component/studio-header/header/div/div/bs-square-button/button"))).click()

upload = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/studio-root/div/ng-component/studio-page-container/div/form/studio-inventory-form-holder/div/studio-panel/div/mat-tab-group/div/mat-tab-body[1]/div/studio-wrapper-track-files/studio-form-files/div/section[1]/div/studio-form-file-box/div/div/div[2]/bs-upload-button/bs-universal-upload-button/div/div/bs-square-button/button'))).click()

drag_and_drop = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[8]/div/mat-dialog-container/ng-component/mat-dialog-content/mat-tab-group/div/mat-tab-body[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button'))).click()
```

Comment: Try to use a refined xpath - like `"//div[@class='drag-drop-container']"` and see if it's working

Comment: wow that worked to open it up, but now I don't know how to paste a file or move around finder to select the certain file I want to upload.

Comment: possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833835/python-selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop

Comment: @Eddy : I think you can use the input field to upload the file without clicking on browse button. Give it a try. `browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.uppy-DragDrop-input[type='file']").send_keys("path/of/the/file")`